# Deleting database records from cakephp NOT WORKING

Tags: database, cakephp, record

Here's my code:

```
function admin_delete($id = null){
    $booking = $this->Booking->read(null, $id);
    if($this->Booking->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Booking deleted');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

and this doesn't seem to work. I've been fiddling with this for ages trying different code etc, using del() as well, but nothing seems to work. The link on the delete button is perfect (eg.com/bookings/delete/id:23), but it just tries to reach the admin_delete.ctp view. which I've clearly asked it to ignore by the redirect.

What am I doing wrong?

my delete link in the view:

```
<?php echo $html->link('Delete', array('action'=>'admin_delete', 'id'=>$booking['Booking']['id']), null, 'Are you sure?');?>
```

HALP!

Comment: `debug($id)` Are you sure the id is there? Also, why read first, then delete? Also, you should make any destructive action into POST requests, or watch Google delete all your records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using admin routing you can not call `'action'=>'admin_delete'` directly, its `'action'=>'delete', 'admin' => true`

Comment: Thankyou very much - this trick works perfectly. sorry for late acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using named parameters, which aren't passed to the function as a parameter.  If you want to keep using named parameters do the following.  In config/routes.php, add:

```
Router::connectNamed(array('id'));
```

Rewrite your admin_delete() function to access the id parameter via the named parameters array:

```
function admin_delete(){
    if(isset($this->params['named']['id']) && $this->Booking->delete($this->params['named']['id'])) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Booking deleted');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        exit();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep it simple and just not use named parameters, you can just update your delete link to not use them. (remove "'id'=>"):

```
<?php echo $html->link('Delete', array('action'=>'admin_delete', $booking['Booking']['id']), null, 'Are you sure?');?>
```